# GO Negotiation Failure issue

Tags: linux, p2p, wifi-direct

I was trying to setup a connection between two devices using WiFi direct (also called Wi-Fi P2P) and followed the steps described in https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/IVI/Wi-Fi_Direct. However it showed that the devices are capable of finding each other through the command "p2p_find", however, when I input the command "p2p_connect  pin/pbc" on both devices, it indicates that the GO Negotiation Failure issue. Below is a detailed information about the devices we used and the operations we did.

### Hardware and software

```
2 USB Wi-Fi devices: TP-link WN722n with atheros chipset ar9271,
```

Operation system: fedora 20 (64 bit),

```
wpa_supplicant version: 2.1,
```

Wireless driver: backpoints 3.13.2-1

### .config:

```
CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE=y
CONFIG_WPS=y
CONFIG_WPS2=y
CONFIG_P2P=y
CONFIG_AP=y
```

### wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1
device_name=p2p_go
device_type=1-0050F204-1
update_config=1
```

### Steps followed:

```
1, command "p2p_find" on both devices A and B   
2, command "p2p_peers"                                
3, command "p2p_group_add" on only device A                                           
4, command "p2p_connect <Device_A_MAC> pin display" (here it will display a PIN_CODE)       
5, command "p2p_connect <Device_B_MAC> <PIN_CODE>"
```

It shows that P2P-GO-NEG-FAILURE status=-1, and I also tried the commands described in

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts, However it cannot fix/workaround the Go Negotiation Failure issue

So I was wondering if I was missing something in the above steps or the chipset (ar9271) not fully support Wi-Fi direct feature?

Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

the value of `p2p_go_intent` in `p2p_supplicant.conf` maybe same in GO and GC device;
I change `p2p_go_intent` from 6 to 14 in GO device and find GO Negotiation success.